# Meaning of the single quotes in 998'244'353

Tags: c++, single-quotes

I recently came across the following C++ code snippet:

```cpp
int Mod = 998'244'353;
```

I was intrigued by the use of single quotes in this number.
Could someone elaborate on what this gets interpreted as and why is it accepted?
Also has this formatting always been there in c++?